# Reading an Int from a file as an Object, and then converting it back to an Int - Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

The reason I do not read it as an int initially is because I am also reading in non-int characters.
The file looks like this:

James 80

Dave 90

Ty 64

I'm using this to occupy the ArrayList:

```
while (scan.hasNext()){ //while end of file not reached
        n.add(scan.next()); 
        count++;            
    }
```

However when I want to take out the integers from the array using instanceof, it seems that

```
(n.get(i) instanceof Integer)
```

returns false for every value in the array, even though it has been occupied correctly e.g.

```
{James, 80, Dave, 90, Ty, 64}
```

I used the logic that every other object will be an integer, so;

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.size() ; i++){

        if(n.get(i) instanceof Integer){
    ....
    }
}
```

This should let me filter out only integers, but my program isn't entering the if statement.

Is there a flaw in my logic or do I need to find a way to collect the int before putting it in the ArrayList, if so could you give me a clue as to what I would need to do?

Comment: `Scanner.next()` returns a `String` so it cannot be an `Integer`.

Comment: Right, but what logic would I use to predetermine an Integer from a String before putting it in the array ?

Comment: You can either parse the input using `Integer.parseInt(String)` or you can use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` and `Scanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: If you had defined your `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<Integer>` you would already have caught and identified this problem at compile time.

Comment: I didn't explain properly but I also wanted to keep the names in the Array, I found the right answer thanks to @Bubletan.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hasNextInt method seems to have solved the problem.

```
while (scan.hasNext()){ //while end of file not reached
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            n.add(scan.nextInt());
        }else{
            n.add(scan.next());
        }
```